# Android Layout Weight Views Being Cut Off

Tags: android, xml, listview, user-interface, android-fragments

Ok so I have a fragment that I want to display two TextViews and a ListView where the first TextView takes up a small bit at the top of the layout and the rest of the space is devided evenly between another TextView and a ListView. However with my current layout the ListView is cutting off the other two TextViews into a very small space. I think it might have to do with the `layout_weight` attibute.

**fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Loading ..." 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:text="Loading ..." />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_pre_cert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0px">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Current Layout**

[image: Current Layout with the TextViews being cut off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the heights to end up being 10%, 45%, 45%, then in addition to setting those weights that you have, set layout_height to be 0dp for each of those views. Layout weights work on *remaining* space.